# Matrix optimization in NLopt

Tags: vectorization, julia, nlopt

[NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) is a solver for optimization, which implements different optimization algorithms and is implemented in different languages.

In order to use the LD_LBFGS algorithm in Julia, does the variable have to be a vector as opposed to a matrix?

If yes, once we need to optimize an objective which is a univariate function of a matrix variable, do we have to vectorize the matrix to be able to use this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, NLopt only understands vectors of decision variables. If your code is more naturally expressed in terms of matrices, then you should convert the vector into a matrix in the function and derivative evaluation callbacks using `reinterpret`.